# more elegant way to do this? python multiples of 2, 3 or 4

Tags: python, concatenation

Write a program that returns the number given. But for multiples of two return "Fizz" instead of the number, for the multiples of three return "Buzz", and for the multiples of four return "Bang". For numbers which are multiples of both two and three return "FizzBuzz". For numbers which are multiples of both two, three, and four return "FizzBuzzBang"

```
def fizz_buzz_bang(i):
    x="Fizz"
    y="Buzz"
    z="Bang"
    if i%2!=0 and i%3!=0 and i%4!=0:
        return i
    if i%2==0 and i%3==0 and i%4==0:
        return x+y+z
    elif i%2==0 and i%3==0:
        return x+y
    elif i%3==0 and i%4==0:
        return y+z
    elif i%2==0 and i%4==0:
        return x+z
    elif i%2==0:
        return x
    elif i%3==0:
        return y
    elif i%4==0:
        return z
```

Comment: You can define 3 function that returns empty if not mult nd the strings if mult then Just call them all and concatenate

Comment: How will `elif i%3 ==0 and i%4` case ever get met if its the same as if `i%2 == 0 and i%3==0 and i%4 ==0`?

Comment: and also `if i%2 ==0 and i%4 == 0` is the same as `i%4 ==0`

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can even have a general solution that should work for any such game

```
def game(rules, i):
    return ''.join(word for divisor, word in rules if not i%divisor) or i  # Possibly str(i)

_fizzbuzzbang_rules = sorted({2: "Fizz", 3: "Buzz", 4: "Bang"}.items())

def fizzbuzzbang(i):
    return game(_fizzbuzzbang_rules, i)  # You could also use partial
                                         # fizzbuzzbang = partial(game, _fizzbuzzbang_rules)
```

Some examples:

```
>>> fizzbuzzbang(2)
'Fizz'
>>> fizzbuzzbang(3)
'Buzz'
>>> fizzbuzzbang(5)
5
>>> fizzbuzzbang(12)
'FizzBuzzBang'
```

Comment: This is dope! gj

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more elegant, but it's more readable and slightly more efficient.

```
def fizz_buzz_bang(i):
    fizz = not i % 2
    buzz = not i % 3
    bang = not i % 4
    if fizz:
        if buzz:
            if bang:
                return 'FizzBuzzBang'
            return 'FizzBuzz'
        return 'Fizz' if not bang else 'Bang'
    if buzz:
        return 'Buzz'
    return i
```

EDIT: Actually, this is probably the simplest way...

```
def fizz_buzz_bang(i):
    if not i % 12:
        return 'FizzBuzzBang'
    if not i % 6:
        return 'FizzBuzz'
    if not i % 4:
        return 'Bang'
    if not i % 3:
        return 'Buzz'
    if not i % 2:
        return 'Fizz'
    return i
```

Comment: This is better but I was thinking instead of manually generating `12` why dont we use a lcm formula `lcm = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y//gcd(x, y), range(2,4+1))`  or even `4*3` so we are using the given variables to generate conditions, same with `6`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```
def fizz_buzz_bang(i):        
    x="Fizz"
    y="Buzz"
    z="Bang"

    x1 = 2 if i%2 == 0 else 1
    y1 = 3 if i%3 == 0 else 1
    z1 = 4 if i%4 == 0 else 1

    a = x1*y1*z1

    return {
                2 : x,
                3 : y,
                4 : z,
                6 : x+y,
                8 : x+z,
                12: y+z,
                24: x+y+z
            }.get(a, i)
```

It's just a mapping that multiply the numbers according to your logic and return a the desired word based on the multiplication result

Answer (score 0):

How about something where we aren't performing calculations for LCM manually

```
def fizz_buzz_bang(i, a, b, c):
    x = 'Fizz'
    y = 'Buzz'
    z = 'Bang'
    if not i % b * c:
        return x + y + z
    elif not i % a * b:
        return x + y
    elif not i % c :
        return z
    elif not i % b:
        return y
    elif not i % a:
        return x

fizz_buzz_bang(12, 2, 3, 4)
```

> ```
> FizzBuzzBang
> ```